# Entering dynamic time using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

How can i enter a specific time from an input.

Example:

```
New York today time is: 4:00 AM, February 11, 2020
Chicago  today time is: 5:00 AM, February 11, 2020
California today time is: 6:00 AM, February 11, 2020
My Current timezone is: 7:00 AM, February 11,2010 -> This text is only the editable my current timezone.
```

if the user change the "my current timezone to 7:00AM to 9:00AM

The New York/Chicago/California will have to advance 2 hours so the output will be.

Output:

```
New York today time is: 6:00 AM, February 11, 2020
Chicago  today time is: 7:00 AM, February 11, 2020
California today time is: 8:00 AM, February 11, 2020
My Current timezone is: 9:00 AM, February 11,2010
```

is this possible using moment.js? i am using moment timezones library.

any help would be really appreciated.

here is my current work: https://jsfiddle.net/rmallari/gr06mxow/19/

Comment: Did you manage to do the first piece (showing timezones before the change)?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes sir. i am sorry i forgot to include it, i already editted my question.

Comment: Hello @Janessa, I think you should have only one date, formatted differently with your moment timezone lib. Do you want an example ?

Comment: What's @TarikMerabet said . By default `moment.tz` take the browser timezone. If you want to change it, you need to pass it a different datetime. See their examples: https://momentjs.com/timezone/